# TCL: timeout a proc which may hang

Tags: timeout, tcl

I've created a proc which may just hang there depending on the inputs. Now I want to set a timeout value for it and force it to return and continue other works once the time is up.

The `vwait` way seems don't apply for my case here. If I put `vwait` after my proc, like:

```
after sometime set status timeout
proc_may_hang
vwait status
```

If the proc hangs, the `vwait` will never be executed, event loop never got started and system does not know about monitoring the variable status either.

And I cannot use multi-threading to start a monitoring process either. The TCL interpreter is from a EDA software, the Thread package is not available.

So is there anyway to force the proc to return? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What kind of hang event  could happen ? IO blocking call ?

Comment: @Dinesh Sorry for not clarifying this. The proc hangs simply because the there are tons of computing tasks to do, and there isn't any response even after a long time. The proc contains nothing more than some calculating commands. This happens a lot in EDA software, and I want to skip this job if the hang happens and jump to the next one. I hope I have expressed myself clearly.

Comment: My first thought is to create a slave interpreter and push the calculations into that. It seems it would be easier to kill that interpreter. That may be overkill though.

Comment: There's a time limit API, but it applies to interpreters (so beneath the level of threads and processes) *and* it won't help all that much if the software goes off and does a lot of work in C.

Comment: @glennjackman Interesting approach. I will do some google about slave interpreter and see if I can get any help from it. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @DonalFellows I'm afraid the process cannot be touched, because in the area of integrated circuit design, it usually takes several hours just to let the EDA software restore the session and get ready to actually to some work. So I can't kill the process just because one proc hangs. Anyway, thanks for helping me.

Comment: Can you show an example procedure? Is it looping, or just executing a single long-running command? More detail is required, but this may be possible!

Comment: @Will Firstly I was asking for both looping and one single command. And then I through it's easy to add some time checking commands in the loop and solved half of the problem. Now the rest is the harder one: to timeout a single command that may hang. That command is a EDA tool builtin command, so I cannot touch the inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Threads can help but there's a bit of wireup needed.  Here's an example of threading that kills long running threads.

```
package require Thread

# Create a thread with needed procs for calculation.=.

proc spawn {} {
    set t_id [thread::create {

        # Source your program here.
        # Make sure to have thread::release when calculation is final.
        # source myfile.tcl

        # this is an example proc
        proc do_calculation {params} {
            # add this to your program
            # get your params for calculation from item
            foreach {parent_id callback index item} $params {}

            set i 10000

            while {$i > 0} {
                incr i $item
                if {$i > 99999} {
                    set i 10000
                }
            }

            # Run something when calculation is done here...
            puts "All done! i = $i"

            # Or in the parent thread in item_complete 
            thread::send -async $parent_id [list $callback $index $item]
            thread::release
        }

        # Don't change beleow. The thread::wait keeps the thread running
        # so can send it a command.
        thread::wait
    }]
}

proc check_thread {t_id seconds callback {started 0}} {

    # If the thread doesn't exist then it probably finished and called thread::release.
    if {[thread::exists $t_id] == 0} {
        $callback
        return
    }

    # Check the time remaining for the thread to complete.
    set now [clock seconds]

    if {$started == 0} {
        set started $now
    }

    set seconds_remaining [expr {$seconds - ($now - $started)}]

    puts "$seconds_remaining seconds remaining."

    # Stop the thread if it took too long.
    if {$seconds_remaining < 1} {
        puts "Times up... stopping thread `$t_id`."
        thread::release $t_id
        $callback
        return
    }

    # Check the thread again in 1 second.
    after 1000 [list check_thread $t_id $seconds $callback $started]
}

# some fake data. Package your data into a list of items to process.
set items [list 1 -1 9 -9 20 -20]
set items_i 0

proc next_item {} {
    global items
    global items_i

    if {$items_i < [llength $items]} {
        set item [lindex $items $items_i]
        incr items_i
        set t_id [spawn]
            # Tell the thread to run the calculation.
            thread::send -async $t_id [list do_calculation [list [thread::id] item_complete $items_i $item]]
        check_thread $t_id 10 next_item 
    } else {
        puts "Items completed. exiting."
        exit
    }   
}

proc item_complete {index item} {
    puts "Item #${index} completed successfully. Item = ${item}."
}

next_item

vwait forever
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried multi-threading already, and the method failed because in the EDA tool I don't have Thread package at all. :(